# Adding new column to DataFrame with values dependent on index ref

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column to this DataFrame in Pandas where I assign a StoreID rolling thru the indexes:

It currently looks like this:

```
   Unnamed: 12  Store  
0          NaN      1  
1          NaN      1  
2          NaN      1  

0          NaN      1  
1          NaN      1  
2          NaN      1  

0          NaN      1  
1          NaN      1  
2          NaN      1  

0          NaN      1  
1          NaN      1  
2          NaN      1
```

I want it to look like this:

```
   Unnamed: 12  Store  StoreID
0          NaN      1  1
1          NaN      1  1
2          NaN      1  1
0          NaN      1  2
1          NaN      1  2
2          NaN      1  2
0          NaN      1  5
1          NaN      1  5
2          NaN      1  5
0          NaN      1  11
1          NaN      1  11
2          NaN      1  11
```

The variable changes upon the index hitting 0.  The report will have variable numbers of items - most of them being 100's of 1000s of records per store.

I can create a new column easily but I can't seem to work out how to do this!
Any help much appreciated - I'm just starting out with Python.

Comment: Why doesn't your output have index values of 3?

Comment: Just an inconsistency on my part.  They should be the same

Comment: Any reason why the StoreID jumps from 2 to 5 then to 11?

Comment: It's just a list of references from stores that have no logic. I could map the 0,1,2 sequence to the customer sequence (0=1, 1=2, 2=5, 3=11) but is there a simpler way that doesn't require another operation ?

Comment: Okay, then I think one of the three solutions below answers you question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the `cumsum` of the diff of the indexes

```
df['g'] = (df.index.to_series().diff() < 0).cumsum()

0    0
1    0
2    0
0    1
1    1
2    1
0    2
1    2
2    2
0    3
1    3
2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.ndarray.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html):

```
df['g'] = (df.index == 0).cumsum() - 1

print(df)

   col  Store  g
0  NaN      1  0
1  NaN      1  0
2  NaN      1  0
0  NaN      1  1
1  NaN      1  1
2  NaN      1  1
0  NaN      1  2
1  NaN      1  2
2  NaN      1  2
0  NaN      1  3
1  NaN      1  3
2  NaN      1  3
```

Comment: I like the idea directly get the result from the index

Comment: These are good suggestions but ideally I want the new column to roll through a custom number or text sequence (i.e. 1, 2, 5, 11) as opposed to (0, 1, 2, 3...). 
Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Comment: @user10011212, So, to be clear, you have an *additional* input specifying the "custom sequence", e.g. we can use `L = [1, 2, 5, 11]` as an input? Can you update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC Try `cumcount`

```
df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
Out[11]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
0    1
1    1
2    1
0    2
1    2
2    2
0    3
1    3
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's reply.  I have ended up solving the problem with:

```
table['STORE_ID'] = (table.index == 0).cumsum() - 1
```

then adding some logic to lookup the store_id based on the sequence:

```
table.loc[table['STORE_ID'] == 3, 'STORE_ID'] = 11
table.loc[table['STORE_ID'] == 2, 'STORE_ID'] = 3
table.loc[table['STORE_ID'] == 1, 'STORE_ID'] = 2
table.loc[table['STORE_ID'] == 0, 'STORE_ID'] = 1
```

I imagine there's a simpler solution to get to the Store_ID sequence quicker but this gets the job done for now.