# Unexpected behavior when creating a column based on a calculation done on a reset_index

Tags: python, pandas

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51622604/6671176), I came across what I thought was unexpected behavior when I tried to create a column based on a basic calculation done on the index of a dataframe. **I'm not really looking for solutions, but trying to figure out *why* this is happening**. I might be overlooking something basic...

## setup:

```
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,9), index=[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2])

>>> df
   0
0  3
1  4
2  2
0  4
1  4
2  1
0  2
1  2
2  2
```

## Weird behavior:

Let's say I was trying to get the cumulative sum of where the index is equal to 0. I can get this easily in such a way:

```
>>> df.reset_index()['index'].eq(0).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

However, if I try to assign this directly to a new column, the result is not right:

```
df['new_column'] = df.reset_index()['index'].eq(0).cumsum()

>>> df
   0  new_column
0  3           1
1  4           1
2  2           1
0  4           1
1  4           1
2  1           1
0  2           1
1  2           1
2  2           1
```

The same occurs if I do it using `assign`:

```
df.assign(new_column = df.reset_index()['index'].eq(0).cumsum())
```

## Expected behavior:

I would have expected the outcome to look like:

```
>>> df
   0  new_column
0  3           1
1  4           1
2  2           1
3  4           2
4  4           2
5  1           2
6  2           3
7  2           3
8  2           3
```

## Workarounds:

There are plenty of workarounds, such as:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'tmp'})

df['new_column'] = df.tmp.eq(0).cumsum()

df.drop('tmp', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Or

```
df.loc[0,'new_column'] = 1

df['new_column'] = df['new_column'].fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
```

## Question:

But as I say, I'm only interested in **Why the new columns are being set to 1 in when I assign them directly from `reset_index()`**

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because pandas set this matching to the index.

Your series is :

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
```

Values for index 0, 1 and 2 above are all `1`.

Once your `df` has only these values as index, it will assign 1 to all rows.

Comment: Ahh! So simple! I figured I was overlooking something silly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Although being novice to Data Frames, I wa able to solve it using

```
df['new_column'] = df.reset_index()['index'].eq(0).cumsum().values
```

I still have to figure out "why". Ok, without `.values` you get `pandas.core.series.Series` while the values returns a numpy array which can straightforwardly be assigned to a new column.

Comment: This happens because `.values` yields a numpy array, which has no index. So pandas just assigns values sequentially and not based on index-matching

Comment: Yes, I was about to edit it in my answer after my quick search.